# PHP mail script won't work properly

Tags: php, javascript, html, email

Allright, so I am pretty new to PHP so I thought I would ask you guys what I am doing wrong. I am currently developing a website were you can contact the company through this e-mail form.

However, for some reason the email won't be delivered. I have tried multiple e-mails (and played a little with the code) and it just won't work.

Here is the mail.php script:

```
    <?php
if ($_POST) {
    $name  = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $text  = $_POST['text'];

    //send email   
    mail("myemail@gmail.com", "email enquiry", $text, "From:" . $email);
}

?>
```

Here is the snippet about the form from my script.js:

```
    //Contact Form Code:
        $(function (e) {
            $(".form-button").click(function (e) {
                var $error = 0;
                var name = $("#form-name").val();
                var email = $("#form-email").val();
                var text = $("#form-msg").val();
                var security = $("#form-security").val();


                if(name == "" || email=="" || text=="" ){
                    $('#details-error-wrap').fadeIn(1000);
                    $error = 1;

                }else{
                    $('#details-error-wrap').fadeOut(1000);
                }

                if(security != 8 ){
                    $('#security-error-wrap').fadeIn(1000);
                    $error = 1;

                }else{
                    $('#security-error-wrap').fadeOut(1000);
                }

                if( /(.+)@(.+){2,}\.(.+){2,}/.test(email) ){

                } else {
                  $('#details-error-wrap').fadeIn(1000);
                  $error = 1;
                }



                var dataString = 'name=' + name + '&email=' + email +   '&text=' + text;

                if($error == 0){
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "mail.php",
                        data: dataString,
                        success: function () {
                            $('#details-error-wrap').fadeOut(1000);
                            $('#security-error-wrap').fadeOut(1000);
                            $('#form-sent').fadeIn(1000);
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                }

                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });


});
```

And lastly, here is the HTML:

```
        <div class="seven columns">

        <div id="form-sent" class="hide">   
            <div class="alert-box success">Message sent: Thankyou for your enquiry</div>
        </div>
        <form id="contact-form">
            <label>Name *</label>     
            <input id="form-name" type="text"/>
            <label>Email *</label>
            <input id="form-email"  type="text" />
            <label>Message *</label>
            <textarea id="form-msg"></textarea>
            <div id="details-error-wrap"  class="hide"> 
            <div class="alert-box alert error-box">Error: Please ensure all fields are filled in correctly</div>
            </div>
            <label>Security Question *</label>
            <input id="form-security" type="text" placeholder="7 + 1 = ?" />
            <div id="security-error-wrap"  class="hide">    
                <div class="alert-box alert error-box">Error: Security question is incorrect</div>
            </div>  
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="form-button right" />

        </form>

    </div>
</div>
```

I posted all three related things. Parts of this website is from a template I'm using, so if you think the problem is in a different file just let me know.

Thanks in advance, I hope someone is able to help me :)

Comment: Does the server where this script is hosted have an SMTP server installed?

Comment: Did you check the return value of mail() for failure? Did you check your mail server's logs to see if anything was handed over from PHP? Anything in the logs that'd indicate the receiving end rejected the mail? Tons of stuff YOU have to check

Comment: Warning: Your script is vulnerable to being hacked by spammers. If you use dynamic headers (eg the `From` field populated from `$_POST`), you **must** properly sanitise the input, otherwise your mail can be hacked to send arbitrary spam to anyone. Code using PHP's `mail()` function is often vulnerable because it doesn't do anything to help you avoid it. I strongly recommend using a decent mailer class such as [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), which will do all the security stuff for you (plus a whole bunch of other nice features).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it might be ending up in your **SPAM** folder.

Are you sending the email using your **personal email address**? Such as me@gmail.com?

If so, that's obviously not going to work, you need to setup **SMTP** in order for the emails to get passed the firewalls and to actually make it to the inbox.

Might want to format your script better, also, use an IF statement to see if the email is actually being sent by the PHP:

```
 $to = 'myemail@gmail.com'; //Change this to the email you're using
 $subject = 'Website Contact Form';
 $headers = "From: " . "Me!! <myemail@gmail.com>" . "\r\n"; //This too
 $content  = "Hey!";

 if (mail($to, $subject, $content, $headers)) {
  echo "Success! Email was sent - Yay!";
 } else {
  echo "Error sending Email! booo!";
 }
```